# Indent multiline string in ERB

Tags: ruby, string, erb

I have a string from an external library that looks like this:

```
s = "  things.each do |thing|\n    thing += 5\n    thing.save\n  end\n\n"
```

This input string isn't going to change. I need to insert it into a file using ERB. e.g.:

```
erb = ERB.new("<%= s %>")
File.write("test.txt", erb.result(instance_eval('binding'))
```

My problem is the indentation. Without making any changes to the string, the file will be written like this:

```
  things.each do |thing|
    thing += 5
    thing.run
  end
```

Note the indentation. What I want to do, however, is to insert the text uniformly indented another two spaces in, like so:

```
    things.each do |thing|
      thing += 5
      thing.run
    end
```

If I do this:

```
erb = ERB.new("  <%= s %>")
```

Then only the first line will be indented.

```
    things.each do |thing|
    thing += 5
    thing.run
  end
```

I *can* achieve this by modifying the initial string..

```
erb = ERB.new("<%= s.gsub(/  (\w)/, "    \\1") %>")
```

.. but that feels a bit messy. I don't really want to do that in the view. Is there a way to indent the entire string in ERB, or am I out of luck? I think I might be.

Comment: Have you tried this? `ERB.new("<%= '  ' + s %>")` (that's a 2-space string being prepended).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative solution that's a bit simpler (but less extendable):

```rb
def indent(str, amount)
  ' ' * amount + str.split("\n").join("\n" + ' ' * amount)
end
```

Comment: I used this code (minus the method definition) in an erb meant to pump out a multi-line string of code into a properly indented YAML variable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is any builtin solution for your problem. But this does not mean you shouldn't just build your own :)

Something like this should work:

```
class CodeIndenter < Struct.new(:code, :indentation)
  def self.indent(*args)
    self.new(*args).indent
  end

  def separator
    "\n"
  end

  def indent
    code.split(separator).map do |line|
      indentation + line
    end.join(separator)
  end
end

s = "  things.each do |thing|\n    thing += 5\n    thing.save\n  end\n\n"
puts CodeIndenter.indent(s, "  ")
```