# Interpolate multiline string with correct indent

Tags: string, interpolation, indentation, multilinestring

When I am trying to interpolate one multiline string into another I get wrong indentation because only the first line of substring has right indent, e.g.:

```
substring = <<-STRING.strip_heredoc
  first line
  second line
STRING

string = <<-STRING.strip_heredoc
  Quote
    #{ substring }
  from substring
STRING
```

The result will be as follows:

```
  Quote
    first line
second line

  from substring
```

Whereas a desired one is

```
Quote
  first line
  second line
from substring
```

My question is almost the same as in [this question about perl and xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501949/multiline-string-replace-with-pretty-indentation), or [this one about erb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381916/indent-multiline-string-in-erb) but a bit more general.

Considering the fact that interpolation could be useful for generating not only any SGML (XML, HTML or ERB) but for SQL and other languages as well...

**Is there any way, method or common practice to interpolate multiline string with correct indentation?**

In case there is no way, **what tool would you recommend for post processing different languages** (e.g. HTML, SQL)

---

Update:

Ruby 2.3 feature `<<~` which is analogue of `strip_heredoc` still (and obviously) adds indent only to the first line of substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I woke up and saw this question and decided to make it a morning programming puzzle to solve.  It was harder than I thought. I'm not thrilled with the API or the complexity, but I didn't want to spend any more time, and it does work.  Maybe you'll find it useful.  If not, perhaps it will at least inspire some other alternative approaches.

I do not know of any libraries or frameworks that meet your needs using plain Ruby Here Documents. [Ruby 2.3 has a new feature](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/multiline-strings-ruby-2-3-0-the-squiggly-heredoc) that basically does what Rails' `#strip_heredoc` does, but I haven't used it and I don't know how it handles multi-line interpolation.  Here is the Ruby code for my custom solution based on your use case (using Ruby 2.0):

https://gist.github.com/shock/1d269a91f938bf1a1c3cba3856bedf19

Comment: Yes, thanks, I am aware of Ruby 2.3 feature. Updated question according to it. Will check your solution

Comment: Nicely done, starred it. May be I'll improve it somehow

Comment: I would suggest to edit your answer and to add that your solution is written in Ruby. Although my question uses Ruby too, there might be other answers considering usage of other languages

Comment: @NickRoz, my answer does state that it uses Ruby 2.0, and since you tagged your question with Ruby and your code is Ruby, I'd be surprised if you get any answers using other languages.  I updated my answer to be more explicit anyway.  I hope you'll accept it, if you go this route.  And if you improve on it, please post your update.  I'd be interested to see it.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I would like to wait a little with accepting answer to collect more different solutions and explanations. Removed tag ruby, I hope it will make question more broad

Comment: I am still waiting for some new answers, but upvote yours. Quite interesting solution.